# Once a function name has been declared as 'virtual', can it ever be be made un-virtual again?

Tags: c++, virtual

So let us say I have some chain of classes where each class is derived from the class before it.  For whatever reason, they all like to use the same name for some member function.  Kinda like this:

```
class C1 { public:             void f() { cout<<"C1"; }; };
class C2 : public C1 { public: void f() { cout<<"C2"; }; };
class C3 : public C2 { public: void f() { cout<<"C3"; }; };
```

Obviously, if I just declare some objects, then call the function f from them, all will call the function associated with their respective object-type:

```
C1 c1; c1.f(); // prints C1
C2 c2; c2.f(); // prints C2
C3 c3; c3.f(); // prints C3
```

Now, if I declare some pointers-to-objects, then call the function f from them, all will call the function associated with their respective pointer-type:

```
C1* p1 = &c1; p1->f(); // prints C1
C1* p2 = &c2; p2->f(); // prints C1
C1* p3 = &c3; p3->f(); // prints C1
C2* p4 = &c2; p4->f(); // prints C2
C2* p5 = &c3; p5->f(); // prints C2
C3* p6 = &c3; p6->f(); // prints C3
```

All of this is super.  I either call the function associated with the object's type or I call the function associated with the pointer's type...

Or of course I could make the function 'virtual'.  Then if I call the function from some object, I will get no change in behavior; however, if I call the function from some pointer, then I won't just call the function for the pointer's type, I will actually call the function for the object-type that the pointer is pointing to.  So far so good.

I can even make the change to virtual mid-way through the chain of inheritance.  Let's say I put a virtual before the function f inside of class C2.  Now the function has been made virtual (i.e. when called from pointers, it uses the object-pointed-to-type instead of the pointer-type to resolve the function call), not only for its own class, but for all future classes that are derived from it.

My question is this:  Once a function has been declared virtual (at some point in the chain of inheritance) can it ever be reverted back to being non-virtual (further down the chain of inheritance)?

For clarification:  When I say revert back to non-virtual behavior, I mean that when I call the function from a pointer, it will use the pointer's type to resolve the function call (and not the object-type that the pointer is pointing to).

Comment: By `C1* p1 = &C1;` etc., you must mean `C1* p1 = &c1;` (i.e. you don't try to take the address of a class).

Comment: Note, you can't make a function virtual halfway through the chain. You hide the original function and introduce a new one. You will only get polymorphic behavior below that point; above it you get static dispatch.

Comment: @Jimmy: what behaviour do you expect when you say "reverted back"?

Comment: @Dennis: That is what I mean when I say "make the change to virtual mid-way through the chain" -- that the function will behave staticly for all classes before introducing the keyword virtual, and then act polymorphic for the class with the virtual keyword, as well as all classes derived from that class. This is possible, yes?

Comment: @larsmans:  Good call, I got a little crazy with the cut and paste.  Fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are visualizing, so here's actual code: `C1* p = &c3; p->f();` That will always call `C1::f` even if `C2` marks the function virtual. But `C2* p = &c3; p->f();` will call `C3::f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once a function has been declared virtual (at some point in the chain of inheritance) can it ever be reverted back to being non-virtual (further down the chain of inheritance)?

No. Once a function signature has been made `virtual` somewhere along the line of inheritance, it will stay that way: every function with the same signature in a derived class will be `virtual` as well.

One way to get around this is to use (abuse?) the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
struct Base {
    virtual void doFoo() { bar(); }
    void foo() { doFoo(); }
};

struct Derived1 : public Base {
    virtual void doFoo() { baz(); }  // "overrides" foo via doFoo
};

struct Derived2 : public Base {
    void foo() { quux(); }  // "un-virtualize" foo by decoupling it from doFoo
};
```

In this inheritance tree, the pointer type will determine which `foo` is called; if it's the one from `Base`, the pointed-to object's type will determine which `doFoo` is called.

Comment: Doesn't C++0x add a `final` keyword to unvirtualize a function?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: IIUC, `final` completely forbids the use of a signature in a base class.

Comment: er... what does that mean? :-)

Comment: Won't work for foo() if you have a Base* pointer to Derived2.

Comment: @yi_H: it works in the sense that it does exactly what I would expect from a non-`virtual` member function: call `Base::Foo`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: that after `struct Base { virtual void f() final; };`, you'll get a compiler error for `struct Derived : public Base { void f(); };` no matter what.

Comment: I don't know what he wants but as far as i can see your solution doesn't solve *anything*. The whole point of using virtual is that you can use Base* pointer. If you use Derived2*, you don't need any of that template method hocuspocus.

Comment: @yi_H: with a `Base*` you will get `virtual` behavior for `foo`, while with a `Derived2*` you will get "un-virtualized" behavior. It's ugly, but it does what an "un-virtualized" member function should do, AFAICT.

Comment: check my solution to see how I undestood the OP's question. and sorry, I now got your point.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No.

If you know how the virtual functions work at C++, you would had know that it is not possible. Putting it simple, for each class there is a table containing a list of virtual functions and the addresses of the overridden functions. When you override a function with virtual, that function will get listed at that list in the table of the class it was declared at, so it will be there for the rest of the inheritance chain.

Comment: The discussion of vtables is an irrelevant implementation detail. C++ could have had a keyword, say `real`, overriding the meaning of `virtual`, and the compiler would have had enough information to decide for every member function declaration whether it should be `virtual` or not.

Comment: Bad Answer: Using an implementation detail as an argument for why something works is not really a valid reason. What happens on implementations that do not use this technique to implement the virtual functions. You need to provide an argument based on the specifications of the language (not a specific implementation).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing :)

Comment: Generally that would be true. But the first standard is from 98 which had been influenced by the language itself as made by Stroustrup(83) and the fact that Stroustrup implemented the language this way (in order to cope with the language Principles including the supermarket Principle and the C backward compatibility) triggered the fact the C++ does not have the keyword real. You are talking as if C++ was first standardized and then implemented. Trust me, if he found a way to allow it without breaking his supermarket Principle and the C backward compatibility Principle, we would have real today

Comment: Even with vtbls, this would be trivial to implement.  For all classes "downstream" of the hypothetical `real`, their vtbl entry for `f()` would simply point at the `f()` of the superclass that declared it `real`.

Comment: but that will beat the supermarket principle in the class that declared it real. instead of being statically binded, the compiler there will put the code for the "dynaimc dispathc" (looking in the vtbl) instead of simple function call. Thus using the vtbl in places it is not needed and beating the supermarket principle (not paying for features that you aren't using).

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer: No.

Once it has been made virtual it will be virtual in all derived classes (even if the virtual keyword is not used later).

For this reason several newer languages force you to use another keyword so that you know that you are overiding a virtual method (as it may not be obvious), but none allow you to un-virtual a method.

Comment: Well, Java offers `final`.  Not quite the same meaning, but it's close.

Comment: I was thinking of C# override

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has already stated, you can't de-virtualise a function, but there's absolutely nothing to stop you from calling the specific version of the function you require, as long as it's legal for the underlying class:

```
C1* p1 = &c1; p1->C1::f(); // prints C1
C1* p2 = &c2; p2->C1::f(); // prints C1, not C2
C1* p3 = &c3; p3->C1::f(); // prints C1, not C3
C2* p4 = &c2; p4->C2::f(); // prints C2
C2* p5 = &c3; p5->C2::f(); // prints C2, not C3
C3* p6 = &c3; p6->C3::f(); // prints C3
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Solving this with template method:

```
class C1 { public:  virtual void f() { g(); }; void g() { std::cout<<"C1"; }; };
class C2 : public C1 { public: virtual void f() { std::cout<<"C2"; }; };
class C3 : public C2 { public: virtual void f() { g(); }};
```

now C3 and it's descendants have C1's behaviour.

Comment: There's nothing "un-virtualized" here, IMHO, since `C3 *p = new C4; p->f();` will call the `f` from `struct C4 : public C3 { void f() { bla(); } };`. This also has nothing to do with the template method pattern. I must admit the OP's requirement is rather vague, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, it it answers you - you may use [novtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attribute in VC++.

Answer (score -2):

no, it cannot be reverted. I never needed this and cannot imagine real-life example of class hierarchy that needs this.

also, it's recommended to avoid deep hierarchy, e.g. by B.Straustrup.

Comment: Just exploring the limits of the language, of which I'm sure Bjarne would aprrove.

Comment: I really doubt. You didn't need this in real project, right? Me too.

Comment: BTW, it's a case when I don't like uncommented downvotes most of all. Now I don't know what was the reason: downvoter regularly meets examples when this feature is useful or it's just my perky style.